# What do boost items do?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I know that if I take damage, bandages and first aid kits can only get me back to 75% health, and after that I have to use something like an Energy Drink (which gives 40 boost) to fully heal, and it seems to do a heal over time effect, unlike bandages and kits which are instant (after the cast time).

Painkillers seem to be another boost item, and give 60 boost.

Does boost do anything besides beside cause the heal-over-time effect? How much can they heal?

Comment: I think I saw it somewhere that they make you run faster but I'm not sure.

Comment: It also seems like you can fully heal with a single "painkillers" but just under with "Energy Drink". And I'm sure the time to consume them are different but I don't have access to the game at the moment to check for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from what you have already mentioned, I believe both items take a different amount of time to consume, (I checked the times yesterday so I might be remembering wrong):

- Painkillers: 8 seconds (or 6... either way it's longer)
- Energy Drink: 4 seconds

I have also found the following [link](http://www.playbattlegrounds.com/news/14.pu) from `28/10/2016` that states this about the boost system (although it may have changed since):

> Added Boost System
>   When Boost Item is used, the blue boost gauge on the right side of HP gauge goes up
>   Character movement speed increases when boost gauge is over 50% and gun aiming accuracy increases when gauge is over 80%

I'm not 100% if this is the case in the current early access game or not but the details of it shouldn't have changed too much since then.

Comment: I couldn't find anything else so far about it and the wiki is basically empty. But I am going to try and find more.